# How to default serialized array of ABBR_DAYNAMES to Sunday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, model-view-controller

How can I make this serialized array default to `Sun` instead of all the `ABBR_DAYNAMES`?

**migration**

```
add_column :challenges, :send_email, :text, default: Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.map(&:downcase)
```

**model**

```
serialize :committed, Array
```

**view**

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :send_email, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
```

[image]

How can we make it default like the second row?

Comment: What about: `default: %w(sun)`?

Comment: I added it to the view @Stefan, but it didn't have an effect. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: The `default: ...` belongs into your migration.

Comment: BTW, have you considered using seven boolean columns (`sun`, `mon`, `tue`, ...) instead of one serialized column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Migration

```
add_column :challenges, :send_email, :text, default: %w(sun)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.select{ |day| day == 'Sun' }.map(&:downcase)
```